# ng-show does not recognize true condition

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I have a problem in AngularJS `ng-show`. I have the following construction:

```
<div class="boxresultados">
      <div ng-click="mostraImovel = true;" id="detImoveis"  ng-repeat="imovel in imoveis_filtrados | orderBy : sortType : sortReverse | paginacao:pag:ipp" >

        <a href="" target="iframe_imv" >

          <div class="thumbresultado">
            <img alt="" height="200px" width="255px" ng-show="imagens.length>0" src="" style="z-index: 2;" />
            <img alt="" height="200px" width="255px" ng-show="imagens.length>0" src="images/semimagem.png" style="z-index: 2;" />
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

When I click in this area I must open my iframe on the same page in popup style.

My iframe:

```
<iframe name="iframe_imv" style="border:none; top:70px;" id="iframe_imv" src="" class="pagimovelshow" ng-show="mostraImovel == true" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

As you can see the iframe has a `ng-show = "mostraImovel == true"`, however, he is not recognizing that this is `true`. I have tested the condition and I saw that it evaluates to `true`, however, my iframe continues to be hide.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and past the code

```
<iframe name="iframe_imv" style="border:none; top:70px;background: red;
    height: 200px;" id="iframe_imv" src="" class="pagimovelshow" ng-show="mostraImovel" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You should provide some explanations on what you did, why it didn't work, and why it should work now. This way, the OP can learn something from your answer. A simple copy/paste won't help him/her improve his/her skills

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your javascript and controller. I am wondering if mostraImovel needs to be specified as a scope variable? Just a thought.